# Alsa cannot set sample format[FFMPEG]

Tags: linux, ffmpeg, command-line-interface, alsa

I am trying to capture a pcm stream from a Roland USB device with ffmpeg and wrap it with wav. The command line I am using is the following:

```
ffmpeg -f alsa -acodec pcm_s32le -ac 2 -ar 48000 -i hw:2,0 out.wav
```

Which comply with the settings of the hardware. I can also capture the stream with Audacity. The problem is that FFMPEG throws **"cannot set sample format error"**. Any idea of what may be happening and how I can fix this?

Thanks in advance.

FFMPEG OUTPUT

```
user@user:~$ ffmpeg -f alsa -acodec pcm_s32le -ac 2 -ar 48000 -i hw:2,0 out.wav
    ffmpeg version N-85548-g3390a2b Copyright (c) 2000-2017 the FFmpeg developers
      built with gcc 5.4.0 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4) 20160609
      configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libvpx --enable-libvorbis --enable-libopus --enable-ffplay
      libavutil      55. 61.100 / 55. 61.100
      libavcodec     57. 92.100 / 57. 92.100
      libavformat    57. 72.101 / 57. 72.101
      libavdevice    57.  7.100 / 57.  7.100
      libavfilter     6. 84.101 /  6. 84.101
      libswscale      4.  7.101 /  4.  7.101
      libswresample   2.  8.100 /  2.  8.100
      libpostproc    54.  6.100 / 54.  6.100
    [alsa @ 0x34b6780] cannot set sample format 0x10008 10 (Invalid argument)
    hw:2,0: Input/output error
```

ARECORD OUTPUT:

```
user@user:~$ arecord -l
**** List of CAPTURE Hardware Devices ****
card 1: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC3236 Analog [ALC3236 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 2: DUOCAPTURE [DUO-CAPTURE], device 0: USB Audio [USB Audio]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

**After Deimus help I checked the setting for my card in arecord and used the correct line for FFMPEG (Notice that I have changed the capture frequency on the hardware).**

ARECORD OUTPUT

```
user@user:~$ arecord --dump-hw-params -D hw:2,0
Recording WAVE 'stdin' : Unsigned 8 bit, Rate 8000 Hz, Mono
HW Params of device "hw:2,0":
--------------------
ACCESS:  MMAP_INTERLEAVED RW_INTERLEAVED
FORMAT:  S24_3LE
SUBFORMAT:  STD
SAMPLE_BITS: 24
FRAME_BITS: 48
CHANNELS: 2
RATE: 44100
PERIOD_TIME: (1020 1981429)
PERIOD_SIZE: [45 87381]
PERIOD_BYTES: [270 524286]
PERIODS: [2 1024]
BUFFER_TIME: (2040 3962858)
BUFFER_SIZE: [90 174762]
BUFFER_BYTES: [540 1048572]
TICK_TIME: ALL
--------------------
arecord: set_params:1233: Sample format non available
Available formats:
- S24_3LE
```

Correct command line

```
ffmpeg -f alsa -acodec pcm_s24le -ac 2 -ar 44100 -i hw:2,0 out.wav
```

Comment: Please put the full error message and format your question to be more readable

Comment: Are you sure that that device supports 32-bit samples?

Comment: I am not sure but I have tried with 24 bit sampling and it gives the same error. 32 is what audacity shows me when it captures.

Comment: If I recall correctly that's what Audacity uses by default–it does not mean the input is 32.

Comment: Exactly! I did not know this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the `--dump-hw-params` option of `arecord` tool to check the supported sample formats.

[Man](https://linux.die.net/man/1/arecord) page for `arecord`

Then you can use the `-sample_fmt` option of `ffmpeg` to specficy the format eg. `s32`

Audio options for ffmpeg are [here](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Audio-Options)

Comment: Perfect! That's the information I needed. The format suggested by arecord for my device is the following: S24_3LE and it handles 24bit. I will be tweaking my command line to suite my device. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

1. Refer to output of `arecord --dump-hw-params -D hw:2,0` where `hw:2,0` is your target device.
2. `arecord` output will show available sample formats under `FORMAT` and `Available formats`. Other useful info is also shown such as `CHANNELS` and `RATE`. Example:

   ```
   --------------------
   ACCESS:  MMAP_INTERLEAVED RW_INTERLEAVED
   FORMAT:  S16_LE S32_LE
   SUBFORMAT:  STD
   SAMPLE_BITS: [16 32]
   FRAME_BITS: [32 64]
   CHANNELS: 2
   RATE: [44100 192000]
   PERIOD_TIME: (83 11888617)
   PERIOD_SIZE: [16 524288]
   PERIOD_BYTES: [128 4194304]
   PERIODS: [2 32]
   BUFFER_TIME: (166 23777234)
   BUFFER_SIZE: [32 1048576]
   BUFFER_BYTES: [128 4194304]
   TICK_TIME: ALL
   --------------------
   Available formats:
   - S16_LE
   - S32_LE
   ```
3. In your `ffmpeg` command choose the appropriate decoder to match the sample format. You can also choose the channels and sample rate:

   ```
   ffmpeg -f alsa -c:a pcm_s32le -channels 2 -sample_rate 44100 -i hw:2,0 output.wav
   ```

Examples of decoders to use:

- `S16LE` = `-c:a pcm_s16le`
- `S24LE` = `-c:a pcm_s24le`
- `S32LE` = `-c:a pcm_s32le`

Also see `ffmpeg -decoders` and [FFmpeg Documentation: ALSA input](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-devices.html#alsa).